# How to toggle div without click

Tags: javascript, angular

this is my html view

```
     <div class="">
        <div class="">
          <section class="accordian" role="tablist" aria-live="polite">
            <article *ngFor="let item of list;let i = index;">
              <div class="section-title" role="tab"  (click)="toggle($event, i)">
                <h3 >{{ item.name }}</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="collapsing-section panel">
               toggle data
              </div>
            </article>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Function i am using for toggle div element here i am passing event and index of array element

```
toggle(event, index) {

const element = event.target;
    element.classList.toggle("active");

    this.list[index].isActive = this.list[index].isActive ? false : true;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
      if(index != i) this.list[i].isActive = false;
    }

    const sib = element.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    // console.log(panel);
    if (sib.style.maxHeight) {
      sib.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      sib.style.maxHeight = sib.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
}
```

Here i want to toggle accordian without mouseclick event

Comment: How do you intend to trigger the function without click event ?

Comment: For me this `(click)` looks very much like a click event

Comment: There aren't mouse click events almost all the time, so that would cause it to flash in and out of existence continuously except during the moment there was a click. (As a rule of thumb you need to say what you want to trigger something as well as what you don't want to trigger it).

Comment: Without mouse click? Can you explain when do you toggle accordion?

Comment: hi Emilien , like in jquery trigger function is there , i make a function for trigger and call this function but in when in console mouse event i get scrollY =0 ScrollX= 0 but when i click with mouse on div element i got some value in scrollY and scrollX

Comment: @GaurangDhorda i m using  in ngOnInit for toggle after getting data from api and i m loading these data in accoudian and i want to toggle from here not from going to click on div element

Answer (score 0):

looks for me like you mixed up the parameters order of the function call.
Look at:

```
(click)="toggle($event, i)" // html

toggle(index, event) { ... } // ts
```